# Search and replace text in all files of a linux directory

Tags: linux, bash, text, sed, grep

I have a website directory where I need to change all hardcoded links from one domain to another.  Looking for a single (grep? sed?) bash command that will allow me to change all occurrences of text in all files in the directory?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The following will do it:

```
sed -i 's/old_link/new_link/g' file...
```

Don't forget to escape any slashes, dots, and any other regex special chars in the link addresses with a backslash.

Comment: You can use alternative delimiters in your `sed` command to avoid having to do some escaping: `sed -i 's|old/with/slashes|new/with/slashes/g'`

Comment: I think you meant: `s|old/with/slashes|new/with/slashes|g`. Yes, you can use a character that would not be valid in a filename, but can be used by sed to delimit a regex, to avoid the escape chars.

Comment: I'm using the 'sed' that came built in to OSX, and I had to use "sed -i .backup 's/old/new/g' *" - i.e. I have to add a 'backup suffix' value for the '-i' flag, which is used to make a backup of files as sed modifies them. These are left around afterwards so I had to do a 'find' to delete them.

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6759339/892648) for recursive replace and omiting directories

Comment: this answer fails if you have non-editable binary files in your directory. will-ob's link should be preferred instead.

Answer (score 2):

Also, try:

```
perl -p -i -e <regex> <folder>
```