# Find and replace with sed in directory and sub directories

Tags: linux, command-line, sed, replace

I run this command to find and replace all occurrences of 'apple' with 'orange' in all files in root of my site:

```
find ./ -exec sed -i 's/apple/orange/g' {} \;
```

But it doesn't go through sub directories.

What is wrong with this command?

Here are some lines of output of `find ./`:

```
./index.php
./header.php
./fpd
./fpd/font
./fpd/font/desktop.ini
./fpd/font/courier.php
./fpd/font/symbol.php
```

Comment: could you run `find ./` and post some sample output? And the directory strucuture please. edit: thanks!

Comment: Hm your find is correct, works for me with subdirs.

Comment: How do you know it does not process subdirectories?

Comment: because it gives these errors: sed: couldn't edit ./fpd: not a regular file
sed: couldn't edit ./fpd/font: not a regular file
sed: couldn't edit ./fpd/font/makefont: not a regula

Comment: oh... i grep for apple and nothing found.they all were replaced. ;) thank you . you opened my eyes !!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Awk/Sed: How to do a recursive find/replace of a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219/awk-sed-how-to-do-a-recursive-find-replace-of-a-string)

Comment: If using zsh, you can use e.g. `src/**/.js`.

Comment: Answer you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49364510/5578292

Comment: The error messages are unnerving, but the command actually does what you want. It's not correct to say it "doesn't work", though it's legitimate and useful to ask how to do this without those warning messages.

Answer (score 560, accepted):

Your `find` should look like that to avoid sending directory names to `sed`:

```sh
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/apple/orange/g' {} \;
```

Comment: You may need to change `sed -i 's/apple/orange/g'` to `sed -i '' 's/apple/orange/g'` to make this work.

Comment: `-i` takes an argument: the extension used to save the temporary file. In GNU sed, looks like there's no space between `-i` and its argument, but in BSD sed there is… so BSD `-i '' 's/foo/bar/'` is equivalent to GNU `-i 's/foo/bar/`.

Comment: Actually adding `-e` does not work on Mac OS. `touch a b c d e` followed by the command above produces a directory listing like this: `a   a-e b   b-e c   c-e d   d-e e   e-e`.

Comment: For Mac OS, this answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242275/re-error-illegal-byte-sequence-on-mac-os-x the `RE error: illegal byte sequence`

Comment: For fish shell users, be sure to quote the empty braces ```'{}'```, because fish automatically expands the empty braces if not quoted.

Comment: Is there are shorter version of this? Pretty lengthy. Or a way to make it an alias/bash function?

Comment: Can someone please explain what is the -exec and the {} \; at the end?

Comment: could this be turned into a shortened alias?

Comment: @quantum231 check

Comment: Can someone else explain the answer to @quantum231's question about what the `{} \;` is doing? The single word explanation isn't quite getting the concept across for me.

Comment: `-exec` tells `find` to execute the following command. `{}` is replaced by `find` with the name of the found file. `\;` tells `find` that its arguments end there, so stop looking for more arguments.

Answer (score 133):

For larger s&r tasks it's better and faster to use grep and xargs, so, for example;

```
grep -rl 'apples' /dir_to_search_under | xargs sed -i 's/apples/oranges/g'
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it was very helpful! If in a git repository, it's even faster using `git grep -l 'apples' | xargs sed -i 's/apples/oranges/g'`

Comment: If on macos, use `xargs sed -i '' 's/apples/oranges/g'`

Comment: If you're trying to replace something with a forward slash in it, you can use `sed` with `|` rather than `/`, e.g. `... xargs sed -i 's|mduuid/apples|mduuid/oranges|g'` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714970/escaping-forward-slashes-in-sed-command

Comment: This fails in xargs 4.8.0. It produces the error `unmatched single quote: by defaults quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option`

Answer (score 14):

Since there are also macOS folks reading this one (as I did), the following code worked for me (on 10.14)

```
egrep -rl '<pattern>' <dir> | xargs -I@ sed -i '' 's/<arg1>/<arg2>/g' @
```

All other answers using `-i` and `-e` do not work on macOS.

[Source](http://blog.daviddemartini.com/replace-text-recursively-using-grep-and-sed-on-macos-osx/comment-page-1/#comment-37921)

Comment: On the mac the accepted answer does work [kind of] - but it spits out 'duplicate' files with <original-filename>-e which would need to be removed / piped into another command (to use verbatim). This method is better though and is still working for me (on 11.2.3)

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i '' 's#NEEDLE#REPLACEMENT#' *.php {} \;
```

Comment: original question doesn't restrict to *.php files, there's also an .ini one

Comment: The unquoted `*.php` is really incorrect; you just got lucky that it didn't get expanded in the starting directory because you didn't happen to have any matching files there.

Comment: Restriction on file name could be obtained with `-name *.php` on the `find` command.

Answer (score 4):

```
grep -e apple your_site_root/**/*.* -s -l | xargs sed -i "" "s|apple|orange|"
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a great program for this called `ruplacer`

https://github.com/dmerejkowsky/ruplacer

Usage

```
ruplacer before_text after_text # prints out list of things it will replace
ruplacer before_text after_text --go # executes the replacements
```

It also respects `.gitignore` so it won't mess up your `.git` or `node_modules` directories (`find .` by default will go into your .git directory and can corrupt it!!!)

Answer (score 0):

I think we can do this with one line simple command

```
for i in `grep -rl eth0 . 2> /dev/null`; do sed -i ‘s/eth0/eth1/’ $i; done
```

Refer to this [page](http://www.geekpills.com/operating-system/linux/search-and-replace-with-sed-in-directory-and-sub-directories/1694/).

Answer (score -7):

In linuxOS:

```
sed -i 's/textSerch/textReplace/g' namefile
```

if "sed" not work try :

```
perl -i -pe 's/textSerch/textReplace/g' namefile
```

Comment: he wants to find all files in sub directories contain that string and replace, not only a single file