# Error when using find and sed

Tags: linux, bash, replace, sed

I am trying to use the find and sed commands in Linux to do the following:

1. When command is issued in current directory it will edit all ".cbf" files in all directories and sub-directories.

I have been using: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758963/find-and-replace-with-sed-in-directory-and-sub-directories), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219/awk-sed-how-to-do-a-recursive-find-replace-of-a-string) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/428493/how-can-i-do-a-recursive-find-and-replace-from-the-command-line) as research references.

My current command that is not working is:

```
find . -name "*.cbf" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's/# change the header/# change the header to something/g'
```

The error I get is: sed: can't read : No such file or directory

I have tried the command both above the directory with the .cbf files and actually in the directory.

Can someone please help me with what I am doing wrong. I simply wish to edit a line in all .cbf
 files in subdirectories from where I am sitting.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you try like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6759339/3297613 ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this `find`/`sed` command:

```
find . -name "*.cbf" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sed -i.bak 's/# change the header/# change the header to something/g' {}
```

Comment: This seems to work too, but same error with : File name too long. Again the files I have are as such "cal_50_01_0001.cbf"

Comment: That is not really very long. Try quoting `'{}'` as in: `find . -name "*.cbf" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sed -i.bak 's/# change the header/# change the header to something/g' '{}'`

Answer (score 2):

Your command actually works. The error you see is related to `-i ''` part which seems wrong. The option to `-i` should be used to provide a suffix for backups when doing an in-place edit, and should be given without any space: `-i.bak`.

If you don't need backups at all, just don't give any extra option after `-i`. In your case `sed` is thinking that extra `''` is a filename and is actually trying to open it (quote from `strace` output):

```
4000  open("", O_RDONLY)                = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

So, the correct command should not have `''` after `-i`.

Comment: So I tried this and I no longer get an error, however once the command is issued is hangs up. It seems like it is working, however I do not see any .cbf files edited.

Comment: If there are a lot of files there, `find` will take time. You could run just the `find` part, without `-print0`, to see how long it takes. It goes through all the files from the current directory, recursively.

Comment: when I issue without print0 it shows all my files very quick then at the end has : File name too long. Any ideas? my file name is cal_51_09_0627.cbf. Should I have a flag to allow this length?