# Recursive grep-sed yields error: sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `?'

Tags: bash, sed, grep, xargs

I am trying to follow the advice in past SO posts:

[Find and replace with sed in directory and sub directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758963/find-and-replace-with-sed-in-directory-and-sub-directories)

and

[awk/sed: How to do a recursive find/replace of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219/awk-sed-how-to-do-a-recursive-find-replace-of-a-string)

but I'm getting an error with the following:

```
grep -r tmp_c . | xargs sed -i  ’s/tmp_c/tmp_c_TEST/g’
```

And this is producing the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `?'
```

I'm not getting anything especially helpful when googling this. Is there some kind of file I might have in my directory that would prompt this sort of error? What else should I investigate?

Comment: Try: `grep -lr tmp_c . | xargs sed -i  's/tmp_c/tmp_c_TEST/g'`

Comment: So, what are you trying to do?

Comment: `grep -r` will output the lines with the matches, not just the filenames. You should be using `grep -rl`, like in the questions you references.

Comment: `’s/tmp_c/tmp_c_TEST/g’` should be `'s/tmp_c/tmp_c_TEST/g'` (no smart quotes).