# Escaping forward slashes in sed command

Tags: bash, shell, sed

With `Bash` and `SED` I'm trying to replace two strings in a js file with URL's.

The two urls that should be inserted is input params when I run the .sh script.

```
./deploy.sh https://hostname.com/a/index.html https://hostname2.com/test
```

However to make this usable in my sed command I have to escape all forward slashes with: `\\` ?

```
./deploy.sh https:\\/\\/hostname.com\\/a\\/index.html https:\\/\\/hostname2.com\\/test
```

If they are escaped this SED command works on Mac OSX Sierra

```
APP_URL=$1
API_URL=$2

sed "s/tempAppUrl/$APP_URL/g;s/tempApiUrl/$API_URL/g" index.src.js > index.js
```

Now I don't want to insert escaped urls as params, I want the script it self to escape the forward slashes.

This is what I've tried:

```
APP_URL=$1
API_URL=$2

ESC_APP_URL=(${APP_URL//\//'\\/'})
ESC_API_URL=(${API_URL//\//'\\/'})

echo 'Escaped URLS'
echo $ESC_APP_URL
#Echos result: https:\\/\\/hostname.com\\/a\\/index.html 
echo $ESC_API_URL
#Echos result: https:\\/\\/hostname2.com\\/test

echo "Inserting app-URL and api-URL before dist"
sed "s/tempAppUrl/$ESC_APP_URL/g;s/tempApiUrl/$ESC_API_URL/g" index.src.js > index.js
```

The params looks the same but in this case the SED throws a error

```
sed: 1: "s/tempAppUrl/https:\\/\ ...": bad flag in substitute command: '\'
```

Could anyone tell me the difference here? The Strings looks the same but gives different results.

Comment: It's not just the `/`s, there's a LOT more characters you have to escape (e.g. the `.`s in your current regexp) but sed won't give you an error message for most of them, it'll just corrupt your output. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed/29626460#29626460. If you want to learn how to do a robust string substitution then post a new question (and the answer will not be sed since sed does not support strings!).

Answer (score 188, accepted):

I suggest to replace

```
sed "s/regex/replace/" file
```

with

```
sed "s|regex|replace|" file
```

if your sed supports it. Then it is no longer necessary to escape the slashes.

The character directly after the `s` determines which character is the separator, which must appear three times in the `s` command.

Comment: Hmm, The SED passed but with wrong result. 
    https:\/\/hostname.com\/a\/index.html

Comment: If your sed supports it? Isn't that a feature of any sed since the epoch?

Comment: When using `|` as separator, you don't need to escape the slashes. Your `ESC_APP_URL=(${APP_URL//\//'\\/'})` lines are completely unnecessary and wrong.

Comment: "If your sed supports it"? Which sed's do not? I have seen the differences in -i '' on mac vs Linux, but this seems to be a regex syntax adopted by more languages/applications, like perl. Can's seem to find much docs about the variant. But in both perl and sed it works on my mac (10.13). So thanks.