# Replace special character "/" using sed command

Tags: sed

I want to replace special character "/" with a special character "*" using sed command.
EXAMPLE-

```
I / YOU.
I * YOU.
```

Comment: We all are here to learn, so please put your efforts which you have tried in order to solve this problem in your post and let us know then.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40715028/3776858

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As detailed in the comment [Escaping forward slashes in sed command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714970/escaping-forward-slashes-in-sed-command)

You can use instead of

```
sed "s/target/replacement/" file
```

either

```
sed "s|target|replacement|" file
```

or

```
sed "s@target@replacement@" file
```

Command:

```
$ echo "I / YOU." | sed 's@/@*@'
I * YOU.
```

More generally when looking at the `sed` accepted syntax:

[sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/sed.html)

[2addr] s/BRE/replacement/flags

> Substitute the replacement string for instances of the BRE in the
>   pattern space. **Any character other than backslash or newline can be**
>   **used instead of a slash to delimit the BRE and the replacement**. Within
>   the BRE and the replacement, the BRE delimiter itself can be used as a
>   literal character if it is preceded by a backslash.

You can also go for another approach in which you do not change the separators but you use the hexadecimal value of the character you want to replace, this will also avoid ambiguity. (http://www.asciitable.com/)

```
$ echo "I / YOU." | sed 's/\x2F/*/'
I * YOU.
```