# replace with special characters

Tags: sed, sh

I have this in `file.txt`: `DISK: [01/08]`, I want to replace the `01` with another variable. I want it with wildcard because there are always other numbers

```
new=05
sed -i "s/DISK: [**/08]/DISK: [$new/08]/" file.txt
```

error is this

> sed: -e expression #1, char 29: unknown option to `s'

Comment: See: [Escaping forward slashes in sed command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40714970/3776858)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping forward slashes in sed command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714970/escaping-forward-slashes-in-sed-command)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the first digit and the following digits with the new number from the variable.

```
new="42"
sed 's/[0-9]\+/'"$new"'/' file
```

Output:

```
DISK: [42/08]
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)