# Find regex text and replace with text that contains brackets and quotes using sed

Tags: sed

I'm trying to use a line of code that will find and replace text with a long string of prefix and suffix code.

Original file:

```
1. 'text that will go here'
2. 'more text that will be here'
3. 'even more text'
```

After replace:

```
youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[height<=360]+bestaudio/best[height<=360]' --postprocessor-args "-ss 0:0:55 -to 0:1:05" "ytsearch1:text that will go here" -o "text that will go here";
youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[height<=360]+bestaudio/best[height<=360]' --postprocessor-args "-ss 0:0:55 -to 0:1:05" "ytsearch1:more text that will be here" -o "more text that will be here";
youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[height<=360]+bestaudio/best[height<=360]' --postprocessor-args "-ss 0:0:55 -to 0:1:05" "ytsearch1:even more text" -o "even more text";
```

I have the following regex which matches #. ' and replaces it but when I try to replace it with the code, sed won't accept it and shoots out an error. This is what I was trying to use:

```
sed -e "s/^.*\d. '/youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[height<=360]+bestaudio/best[height<=360]' --postprocessor-args "-ss 0:0:55 -to 0:1:05" "ytsearch1:/g" original.txt > new.txt
```

I know why it doesn't work, because the replace with has a bunch of slashes and quotes in it, but I have no idea how to get sed to accept those characters to replace with so it doesn't break the entire command.

Answer (score 2):

With extended regular expression:

```
sed -E "s|^.*'(.*)'.*|youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[height<=360]+bestaudio/best[height<=360]' --postprocessor-args \"-ss 0:0:55 -to 0:1:05\" \"ytsearch1:\1\" -o \"\1\";|" file
```

or with regex:

```
sed "s|^.*'\(.*\)'.*|youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[height<=360]+bestaudio/best[height<=360]' --postprocessor-args \"-ss 0:0:55 -to 0:1:05\" \"ytsearch1:\1\" -o \"\1\";|" file
```

See: [Escaping forward slashes in sed command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40714970/3776858)

Comment: It almost works, only problem is it isn't matching my regex exactly. It's doing ^.*instead of ^.*\d. ' and missing the \d part and looks like what also follows it.

Comment: @user2406786 but this gives the output as mentioned in the question.. sometimes there are different ways to solve the same problem.. also note that `sed` doesn't support `\d`, you need to use `[0-9]`