# How to match sequence ../../../ in sed?

Tags: regex, sed

How to realize in sed (regex) the next output?
It is necessary to extract the preceded '../'

input

```
$ ../some/path
$ ../../some/path
$ ../../../any/path/to/folder
$ ../../../../path/to/some/folder
```

output

```
$ ../
$ ../../
$ ../../../
$ ../../../../
```

Comment: input == output ??

Comment: It is necessary to extract the preceded  ../

Comment: @stacker, As already mentioned by anubhava sir, please do add your efforts in your question which is highly encouraged on SO, kindly edit your post and let us know then.

Comment: This might help: [Escaping forward slashes in sed command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40714970/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus Maybe. Just question a bit different.

Comment: Is `$` and the space character part of the file?

Answer (score 0):

I would just do:

```
sed 's@/[^.].*@/@'
```

or (depending on the input and desired behavior):

```
sed -E 's@/[^.]+@/@'
```

Comment: Are you tested it?

Comment: @stacker It works okay on your input sample, producing the desired result.

Comment: Thank you Sir William. That is perfect 'sed -E 's@/[^.]+.*@/@''

Answer (score -1):

Match all repeated `../` prefixes from the beginning and replace the rest with nothing:

```
s#^((\.\./)*).*$#\1#g
```

with extended regular expressions, or with basic regular expressions:

```
s#^\(\(\.\./\)*\).*$#\1#g
```

- `^` matches beginning of line
- `(\.\./)` matches ../
- `*` repeats 0 or more times
- `.*$` matches the rest until the end of line
- `\1` references the first capturing group match

*BUT* this is probably achieved easier with `grep` instead of sed, since you do not need to do the replacing (so likely a bit faster too):

```
egrep -o '^(\.\./)*'
```

`-o` prints only the matching portion of the line.

Comment: Thank you, but this example not working. sed -e 's#^(\.\./)*##g'

Comment: I would add that this requires extended regular expressions (EREs).

Comment: @stacker: Add option `-E` (extended regular expression) to your sed.