# Updating a yaml with a string containing special characters using sed

Tags: linux, sed, yaml

I have a yaml file that needs to be updated with string containing special characters. Here is the command I used but I get sed expression error

Yaml file (file):

```
Key1: 
Key2:
```

Command that works without special characters for $var (env variable):

```
sed  -i '0,/^\([[:space:]]*Key1: *\).*/s//\1'$var'/;' file
```

Value for $var:

> fkugoiuhoiuyflkbbui/qy++bfv7J3c

Error I get is:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 154: unknown option to `s'
```

I am trying to figure out how I can get this working. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your variable contains a `/`. This irritates `sed` a lot.

Comment: Yeah I cannot change the variable since its a fixed value and can contain any special character.

Comment: Can there also be a space in the variable?

Comment: No, there won't be any space

Comment: Then in the `s` command replace the three `/` with one space each. See: [Escaping forward slashes in sed command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40714970/3776858)

Comment: I get an error
`sed: -e expression #1, char 40: unknown command: `;'`

Command: sed  -i '0,/^\([[:space:]]*Key1: *\).* s  \1'$var'/;' file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default delimiter of `sed`  is conflicting with the `/` in your variable. You will need to set a different delimiter, further, the single quotes will not allow the variable to expand.

You can try this `sed`

```
$ sed "\|Key1|s|$|'$var'|" input_file
Key1: 'fkugoiuhoiuyflkbbui/qy++bfv7J3c'
Key2:
```

Comment: Cool, this works. How do I make sure the variable value doesn't get appended on every run of the command and value is updated only for first occurence of "key1"?

Comment: @wasay `sed "0,\|Key1|{/Key1/s|$|'$var'|}" file`

Comment: For some reason this is not working for me. The value doesn't get updated at all

Comment: `sed "0,\|Key1|{/\(.*Key1:\).*/s||\1'$var'|}" file` @wasay

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that can happen no matter what delimiter of `s///` you pick. The proper solution is to handle whatever delimiter characters appear in the data

```sh
escaped=${var//\//\\\/}    # escape all slashes
sed  -i '0,/^\([[:space:]]*Key1: *\).*/s//\1'"${escaped}"'/;' file
```

Breaking that down:

- this uses the `${parameter/pattern/string}` "search and replace" form of [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)
- if the `pattern` starts with a `/`, then it's a *global* search and replace
- the pattern is `\/` which is a single forward slash: it needs to be escaped so that it is not interpreted as the separator between the pattern and the string.
- then comes the `/` actually separating the pattern and the replacement string
- the replacement string is `\\\/`: `\\` is a literal backslash (that needs to go into the sed command) and lastly `\/` is a literal slash.

---

With [yq](/questions/tagged/yq), a YAML processing tool, we can write

```sh
yq -i eval '.Key1 = "'"$var"'"' file
```

This is using the "go" implementaton of yq

> ```
> $ yq --version
> yq (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version 4.25.1
> ```

Comment: This works too. Can you explain why so many slashes in escaped variable please? Thanks Glenn!