# Sed replace for programming language files

Tags: sed

I am using `sed` to remove comment characters at the beginning using `s/${pn_ere}//`.  The delimiter ends up being a problem for C++ code when I have the line start being `//`.

What alternative to `/` could I use that would be safe to use for most programming languages?

```
   sed -n "/$beg_re/,/$end_re/ {
      /$beg_re/d ; /$end_re/z; s/${pn_ere}// ; p`
```

`s/${pn_ere}//` but have to replace the use of `/` and use another delimiter.  In this way I can handle C++ code where comments start with `//`.

Comment: See: [Escaping forward slashes in sed command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40714970/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use "_" for example.

See [here](https://backreference.org/2010/02/20/using-different-delimiters-in-sed/index.html) for more ideas.

Comment: I also wonder what to do with things like `/$beg_re/d` when the `beg_re` pattern also starts with `//`.

Comment: Use e.g. `\|$beg_re|d`

Comment: Would I not need an escape for the second `|` ?

Comment: I actually think that I would be fine using `/`.  Consider `beg_ere="^[[:space:]]*(\/\/)[[:space:]]+"` , then there should be no problem with `/$beg_ere/d` or with `s/${beg_ere}//`.  Am I right?