# Renamed Home directory - Rails won't start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rbenv

My home directory had a bad name on my Mac, so I renamed it. I did this by creating a temp user, signing in as that user, deleting my original user (but preserving the home directory), creating a new real user, and having that new user take the home directory of the old one.

Now, when I try to start Rails, I get this error (See `OLD_USER` and `NEW_USER`):

```
11:41:19 web.1     | started with pid 17653
11:41:19 sidekiq.1 | started with pid 17654
11:41:20 web.1     | bundler: failed to load command: bin/rails (bin/rails)
11:41:20 web.1     | LoadError: cannot load such file -- /Users/OLD_USER/Code/my_project/config/boot
11:41:20 web.1     |   /Users/NEW_USER/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-0.2.14/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require'
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

do a [search/replace on all files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758963/find-and-replace-with-sed-in-directory-and-sub-directories) in the .rbenv directory.

Search for the old path, replace it with the new path.

Comment: This grep returns no results for the old user anywhere in the `.rbenv` directory: ```11:53 AM .rbenv: grep -rin OLD_USER *```

Comment: according to your description the new user should have the same directory location as the old user anyway, right?

Comment: The directory was renamed from OLD_USER to NEW_USER