# Remove space between a keyword and paranthesis

Tags: sed, grep

I have nearly 300 files in 60 folders .

As per the C++ coding guidelines, I need to replace below lines from *.cpp and *.cl files (wants to remove extra space between **if** and **for** statement) -

```
for (* .....)
```

**with**

```
for(* .....)
```

and also

```
if (* .....)
```

**with**

```
if(* .....)
```

Can any one suggest me the **grep** command to do search and replace for all files.

**Edited:**

I tried with below commands:

```
sed -i 's/for (/for(/g' *.cpp
```

But got **error** like below:

```
sed: can't read *.cpp: No such file or directory
```

Comment: If you need/want to do it with grep specifically, then the [Unix&Linux StackExchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com) might be better suited for this question. That being said, there are a lot of code beautification tools which can do that kind of stuff automatically, without having to write a bunch of regular expressions

Comment: You may consider to use the `sed` utility.

Comment: The `grep` utility only *finds*  patterns in files. It doesn't replace with other patterns. As mentioned, see the `sed` program.

Comment: I have updated my question .Instead of grep I need any linux command to do so .

Comment: You should use a formatter instead of replacing manually like this. Currently probably [clang-format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) is the most common one and is supported by almost all IDEs. Visual Studio even includes clang format by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need **sed** command (stream editor, see `man sed` on your mashine). It is more suitable for file editing.

`sed -i -E 's/(for|if)[ ]+(\(.*\))/\1\2/g'`

Let me explain:

1. `-i` stands for *inline*, that means that all changes will be done and saved in the file

2. `-E` is needed to use extended regular expression inside with sed
3. `s/(for|if)[ ]+(\(.*\))/\1\2/g`

   - `s` stands for *substitute*
   - `/` is a separator, which separates different parts of command. Between first / and second / there is pattern that you need to find (and then replace). After second / and third / there that we want to have after substitution.
   - `g` in the end stands for *global*, that means to make changes in the whole file.

**How to apply to every file that you need?**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758963/find-and-replace-with-sed-in-directory-and-sub-directories/35607711) is already exist, so in the end you need to run in directory where are your files stored following command

```sh
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -E 's/(for|if)[ ]+(\(.*\))/\1\2/g' {} \;
```

I hope, this will help:)

Answer (score 0):

I have created the file "brol.txt", with following content:

```
for (correct
for(wrong
if (correct
if(wrong
```

I have launched following grep command:

```
grep -E "for \(|if \(" brol.txt
```

With following result:

```
for (correct
if (correct
```

Explanation:

```
grep -E means extended grep (allows to search for expression1 OR expression2,
                             separated by a pipe character)
\( means the search for a round bracket. The backslash is an escape character.
```

Comment: My files names are different in every folders . So got error ..I have updated my question .

Comment: I advise you to use the `find` utility: `find <start_directory> -name "*.cpp" -exec sed ... {} ... \;`, plenty of examples on this site.

Comment: This quick and dirty attempt will also match `"replacing for () with for()"` and `find_for (x)`, and more problematic: `#define inside_for (x)` that becomes `#define inside_for(x)` which has a very different meaning.